# 'gdk_get_default_root_window' Equivalent in Gtk#?

Tags: mono, gtk, gtk#

I was looking at some native C code, and it referenced `gdk_get_default_root_window`.  I found [the documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-get-default-root-window) on `gdk_get_default_root_window`, but I can't seem to find 
its managed equivalent.

Does anyone know if there is a Gtk# managed equivalent for `gdk_get_default_root_window`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gdk.Global.DefaultRootWindow looks promising.